# Resize a raid1 ntfs partition

Tags: raid, ntfs, software-raid, ntfsresize

My computer is running windows 7 on a software raid1 (ntfs obviously) partition.
I would like to reduce the size of the partition (currently the on whole disk) to install a raid0 (or 1 I don't know yet) with a linux distribution.

Is there any precaution to take before resizing (I know I need to back up precious data) with gparted ?
Is gparted able to take the raid1 into account  and resize it properly ? Otherwise, what is the procedure to still be able to boot on the windows partition (and preserve raid) ?

I can provide further details if required.
Thans for any answer !

Comment: Is the software RAID managed by Windows? If so can you shrink the volume on the Windows side first?

Comment: A screenshot of Disk Management snap-in can help us make sure we can give you the best advice.

Comment: software raid is managed by intel matrix storage console

Answer (score 0):

I would break the mirror, resize and remake the mirror, just to keep things as simple as possible.  I agree, backing up/imaging is always a smart thing to do when modifying partitions.